# iOS : Saving images to app folder and accessing it

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, save-image

I am trying to take an image and place that image to imageView, I am able to do this. But I am not able to save this to device, I want my photo to be saved in my application folder and want to access it from another view.

studentImage is my UIImageView element where I am able to set the image taken from camera.

Here is the code I am working with :

```
  NSString* format = @".png";
  NSString* imagename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",nickname,format];
  UIImage *img = [self.studentImage image];  
  NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
  NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:imagename]; 
  [pngData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

This statement is returning null :  [pngData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

It would be great, if some one can tell me how to access that image from another view.

Comment: Please let me know if I am not clear with Question.

Comment: writeToFile:atomically: returns a BOOL value (not an object)... have you checked that?

Comment: Make sure `pngData` is not `nil`.

Comment: Thanks Nikolai, my pngData is getting nil and I made it to work.